# Cracking Vigenere and Caesar Ciphered Text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, caesar-cipher, vigenere-cipher

I have written a pair of programs in Python that can be used to encrypt, decrypt, and crack Caesar and Vigenere Ciphered text. I am fairly new to Python and I wrote these programs largely to try and test myself on what I had learned so far with a practical problem, although I cannot claim that every line of these programs is my own. I would appreciate feedback related to any aspect of my program: Efficiency of my algorithms, efficiency of my implementation, quality of my Python, overlooked features, bugs, etc.

I have included a sample of text I used for testing below.

**vigenere.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""
    vigenere.py - Vigenere tool, can use statistical analysis to guess keys of varying length for enciphered text

    Options:
        --encrypt - enable encryption mode
        --decrypt - enable decryption mode
        --preserve-spacing - preserve the spacing of the input in the output
        --key - specify the encryption key
        --spacing - specify the output spacing
        --guess - attempt to guess the encryption key by statistical analysis

    Todo:
        - Implement n-gram analysis to improve accuracy of key guesses
        - Perform frequency analysis of deciphered text to improve accuracy of key guesses
    Future:
        - Add support for multiple languages
        - Include standard deviations for each letter frequency
        - Get better numbers for frequency analysis
"""

import argparse
import re
import string
from itertools import cycle

def buildSubStrings(string, seperation): # Build all substrings required to analyse the polyalphabetic cipher
    return [string[i::seperation] for i in range(seperation)]

def frequencyAnalysis(string): # Normalised frequency analysis
    freq = [0] * 26

    for c in string:
        freq[ord(c) - ord('A')] += 1

    total = sum(freq)

    for i in range(0, len(freq)):
        freq[i] /= (float(total) / 100)

    return freq

def initialiseParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Encrypt or decrpyt a string using the Caesar Cipher")

    parser.add_argument("--encrypt", "--enc", "-e", help = "encryption mode (default)", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--decrypt", "--dec", "-d", help = "decryption mode", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--preserve-spacing", "--preserve", "-p", help = "use same spacing as the input text", action = "store_true", dest = "preserveSpacing")
    parser.add_argument("--key", "-k", help = "encryption key for vigenere cipher", type = str)
    parser.add_argument("--spacing", "-s", help = "specify the spacing in output", type = int)
    parser.add_argument("--guess", "-g", help = "Attempt to guess the most likely key value", action = "store_true")

    return parser

def scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift): # Calculates a weighted score for a given shift value
    englishFrequencies = [  8.167, 1.492, 2.782,
                            4.253, 12.702, 2.228,
                            2.015, 6.094, 6.966,
                            0.153, 0.772, 4.025,
                            2.406, 6.749, 7.507,
                            1.929, 0.095, 5.987,
                            6.327, 9.056, 2.758,
                            0.978, 2.360, 0.150,
                            1.974, 0.074 ]

    score = 0

    for index in range(0, 26):
        shiftIndex = (index + shift) % 26
        score += abs(frequencyAnalysis[index] - englishFrequencies[shiftIndex])

    return score / 26

def shiftCalculator(frequencyAnalysis): # Calculates the most likely shift value for a substring by comparing weighted scores of different shift values
    bestGuess = ''
    bestGuessScore = float('inf')

    for shift in range(1, 27):
        score = scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift)

        if score < bestGuessScore:
            bestGuessScore = score
            bestGuess = chr(ord('Z') - shift + 1)

    return bestGuess

def stringPrepare(string, preserveSpacing): # Strip all non alphabetic characters from a string and convert to upper case
    if preserveSpacing == True:
        regex = '[^A-Z\s]'
    else:
        regex = '[^A-Z]'

    return re.compile(regex).sub('', string).upper()

def vigenere(plaintext, key, encrypt):
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    output = ''
    shift = 1

    if encrypt == False:
        shift = -1

    for x, y in zip(stringPrepare(plaintext, False).upper(), cycle(key.upper())):
        output += alphabet[(alphabet.index(x) + alphabet.index(y) * shift) % 26]

    return output

def main():
    parser = initialiseParser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    rawText = stringPrepare(str.upper(input('')), True)
    strippedText = stringPrepare(rawText, False)

    if args.decrypt or args.encrypt:
        if(args.key != None):
            output = vigenere(strippedText, args.key, args.encrypt)
        else:
            print("Error: No key given!")
    elif args.guess:
        maxGuess = 30 if len(strippedText) > 30 else len(strippedText)
        keyList = list()

        for guess in range(2, maxGuess):
            substringList = buildSubStrings(strippedText, guess)
            frequencyAnalysisList = list()
            key = ''

            for subString in substringList:
                frequencyAnalysisList.append(frequencyAnalysis(subString))

            for frequency in frequencyAnalysisList:
                key += shiftCalculator(frequency)

            keyList.append(key)

        bestGuess = ''
        bestGuessScore = float('inf')

        for key in keyList:
            score = scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis(str.upper(vigenere(strippedText, key, False))), 0)

            if score < bestGuessScore:
                bestGuessScore = score
                bestGuess = key

        print("Best key guess: %s\nAttepting decryption..." % bestGuess)
        output = vigenere(strippedText, bestGuess, False)

    if args.preserveSpacing:
        for x in range(0, len(rawText)):
            if rawText[x] == ' ':
                output = output[:x] + ' ' + output[x:] # Reinsert the stripped spaces back into the output
    elif args.spacing:
        if args.spacing > 0:
            output = ' '.join([output[i:i + args.spacing] for i in range(0, len(output), args.spacing)])

    print(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**caesar.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""
    caesar.py - Caesar Cipher tool, can use statistical analysis to guess the shift value of Caesar Ciphered text

    Options:
        --bruteforce - attempt to bruteforce the shift value
        --encrypt - enable encryption mode
        --decrypt - enable decryption mode
        --preserve-spacing - preserve the spacing of the input in the output
        --shift - specify the shift value
        --spacing - specify the output spacing
        --guess - attempt to guess the shift value by statistical analysis

    Todo:
        - Implement n-gram analysis to improve accuracy of key guesses
    Future:
        - Add support for multiple languages
        - Include standard deviations for each letter frequency
        - Get better numbers for frequency analysis
"""

import argparse
import re

def caesar(string, shift):
    return "".join(chr(((ord(char) - 65 + shift) % 26) + 65) if not char.isspace() else " " for char in string)

def frequencyAnalysis(string): # Normalised frequency analysis
    freq = [0] * 26

    for c in string:
        if c.isalpha():
            freq[ord(c) - ord('A')] += 1

    total = sum(freq)

    for i in range(0, len(freq)):
        freq[i] /= (float(total) / 100)

    return freq

def initialiseParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Encrypt or decrpyt a string using the Caesar Cipher")

    parser.add_argument("--bruteforce", "--brute", "-b", help = "bruteforce mode", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--encrypt", "--enc", "-e", help = "encryption mode (default)", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--decrypt", "--dec", "-d", help = "decryption mode", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--preserve-spacing", "--preserve", "-p", help = "use same spacing as original string", action = "store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--shift", "-s", help = "value for the Caesar shift", type = int, choices = range(1, 26))
    parser.add_argument("--spacing", "-x", help = "specify the spacing in output", type = int)
    parser.add_argument("--guess", "-g", help = "use statistical analysis to guess the most likely shift value", action = "store_true")

    return parser

def shiftScoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift): # Calculates a weighted score for a given shift value
    englishFrequencies = [  8.167, 1.492, 2.782,
                            4.253, 12.702, 2.228,
                            2.015, 6.094, 6.966,
                            0.153, 0.772, 4.025,
                            2.406, 6.749, 7.507,
                            1.929, 0.095, 5.987,
                            6.327, 9.056, 2.758,
                            0.978, 2.360, 0.150,
                            1.974, 0.074 ]

    score = 0

    for index in range(0, 26):
        shiftIndex = (index + shift) % 26
        score += abs(frequencyAnalysis[index] - englishFrequencies[shiftIndex])

    return score / 26

def shiftCalculator(frequencyAnalysis): # Calculates the most likely shift value for a substring by comparing weighted scores of different shift values
    bestGuess = ''
    bestGuessVal = float('inf')

    for shift in range(1, 27):
        score = shiftScoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift)

        if score < bestGuessVal:
            bestGuessVal = score
            bestGuess = 26 - shift

    return bestGuess

def main():
    parser = initialiseParser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.bruteforce:
        bruteforce = True
    else:
        bruteforce = False
        shift = args.shift

    if args.decrypt:
        shift = -shift

    if args.preserve_spacing: 
        regex = '[^A-Z\s]'
    else:
        regex = '[^A-Z]'

    string = re.compile(regex).sub('', input().upper())

    if args.spacing:
        string = ' '.join([string[i:i + args.spacing] for i in range(0, len(string), args.spacing)])

    if args.guess:
        shift = shiftCalculator(frequencyAnalysis(string))
        print("Best shift value guess: %d (%c)\nAttempting decryption...\n%s" % (shift, chr(shift + ord('A') - 1), caesar(string, -shift)))
        return

    if bruteforce:
        for shift in range(1, 26):
            print("%d:\t%s" %(shift, caesar(string, -shift)))
    else:
        print(caesar(string, shift))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**rainbow-passage.txt**

> When the sunlight strikes raindrops in the air, they act as a prism
>   and form a rainbow. The rainbow is a division of white light into many
>   beautiful colors. These take the shape of a long round arch, with its
>   path high above, and its two ends apparently beyond the horizon. There
>   is , according to legend, a boiling pot of gold at one end. People
>   look, but no one ever finds it. When a man looks for something beyond
>   his reach, his friends say he is looking for the pot of gold at the
>   end of the rainbow. Throughout the centuries people have explained the
>   rainbow in various ways. Some have accepted it as a miracle without
>   physical explanation. To the Hebrews it was a token that there would
>   be no more universal floods. The Greeks used to imagine that it was a
>   sign from the gods to foretell war or heavy rain. The Norsemen
>   considered the rainbow as a bridge over which the gods passed from
>   earth to their home in the sky. Others have tried to explain the
>   phenomenon physically. Aristotle thought that the rainbow was caused
>   by reflection of the sun’s rays by the rain. Since then physicists
>   have found that it is not reflection, but refraction by the raindrops
>   which causes the rainbows. Many complicated ideas about the rainbow
>   have been formed. The difference in the rainbow depends considerably
>   upon the size of the drops, and the width of the colored band
>   increases as the size of the drops increases. The actual primary
>   rainbow observed is said to be the effect of super-imposition of a
>   number of bows. If the red of the second bow falls upon the green of
>   the first, the result is to give a bow with an abnormally wide yellow
>   band, since red and green light when mixed form yellow. This is a very
>   common type of bow, one showing mainly red and yellow, with little or
>   no green or blue

**Example Vigenere Encryption**

```
./vigenere.py -e -k RAINBOW < rainbow-passage.txt
```

**Output**

> NHMAUVAJUVYJUDKSBEJYAJRIVORNFPAVOHDVAQEUVAPAKGBGWGRQFNOJUFWENONRIVOPKPYEZNJBXFWQFBREMIAVPBKWWPVUSHZGPGJBPFMIAZPARUBVGIHTOTBSGPYEARUOGVTPRTVWGEWSBZKEGZBVBZRRKUXWPYIBFQOPYHQTIOXFVMNOREKSBJPSJUSICQONVNBYZPAPOVQUVAYOZVACJKHMEFWORCKBSREEGBBMSCVNLNCCECIVTQCPFFOBMRWKOVRFBZGEWCMSHFOSOVHJFOVRFJAIFQAEGEKWPROOIRNTBPYOWOZFPAAKHQAHPAPOVQIWOIEIPIVEJFZVFBZJSILISEJLWBLWJXFWEUVAGOBBGUKCDIGUVAVNLBGHDVRIVOPKNTPEPICYOCGUVATEVGVFEVSXRPDHVHIIFSTGLIVOSZKHMEBWJSOEVOJWIIWHTKWPSABNSDRVMNDQAGTMQJHWJAUVSOYCEEVUVKLTXUZGETATRYDHRNIGJCJKOBUFVASRMJTWPNAANUCGVNBUBHPYEZRXCQCDJROCIFRMHOWRVRANMTHFOLFUVAXRMRLGQJELGPWIRGQAFHDRTQGXOORSQTOTNFMBUFUKUSBBGCNVTMYMKWIOZUFORPRIVOHDVNWETSIVNKBOGEUEZREHDVRIVOPKNAANCFEUGMBWSNNHQPIHDVGWQTDWJSMQGFKDEIEUVPFTPRJFDFMMVOHDVSSLPHDVRAUBJAKRQREHKVXXYBWJKHMCISJFMMAPBLYYAVDOHCYIEJGPFTTRUVKLGPGUVWKTPRSOEEBWJXOOTACFFRXPRMSMSYKIWAPTPYEAHOGNRYAOZHDVRIVOGEECMGISJGHGFJQEJTAUBJAWOCAEHDRTQGJGJFTZRGZATTQBOPQKRMSSOYKIWACMPYEZNJBZIOXFXVETHKNVGAJTPRSOEEBWJTAWEYKBNDHZCIGFREUEIFBPKLTBUFFWZNJBXVWMEJRFBBFRUREHDVDQSGSNVNKRJBPYEZNJBXFWLRQSJUSKBOGEUEZNCZULPWAUVAJIHRPTPYELEPDORNLGISSZDBUPTPYEKBMCNVDJNOREECZRBGAJAAGISOZZMBGHDVDZBQGEECZRBGAJTPRBQPLATCSWIRRGEBWJSOEBCGAIVMQJGORILGPPAKHMRGTATTWSTILVRQZQCOZTQBOCBRNCZCSNFFJBXGEWTPRSSZFFBUFGATOVQCCSWATYTILFNBUFUNVEVBGHDVFQETHPYEZRTIHKIAGPUEMEIOPKSZTPNOOXEOZZBZHPWQQFMACLWJCOJUSQADSNVDIAEUNVEVYJUDKWPROAEOELSPFIPETYPKPYIAVTORVRGPPAIFNBLQSKWBWJPBAJHWJJBCDAQAMMNVDIAEMACLWJXWPYLQGUZAFRVBHFAVNWECZQV

**Example Vigenere Cracking**

```
./vigenere -g < ciphertext.txt
```

**Output**

> Best key guess: RAINBOW
>   Attepting decryption...
>   WHENTHESUNLIGHTSTRIKESRAINDROPSINTHEAIRTHEYACTASAPRISMANDFORMARAINBOWTHERAINBOWISADIVISIONOFWHITELIGHTINTOMANYBEAUTIFULCOLORSTHESETAKETHESHAPEOFALONGROUNDARCHWITHITSPATHHIGHABOVEANDITSTWOENDSAPPARENTLYBEYONDTHEHORIZONTHEREISACCORDINGTOLEGENDABOILINGPOTOFGOLDATONEENDPEOPLELOOKBUTNOONEEVERFINDSITWHENAMANLOOKSFORSOMETHINGBEYONDHISREACHHISFRIENDSSAYHEISLOOKINGFORTHEPOTOFGOLDATTHEENDOFTHERAINBOWTHROUGHOUTTHECENTURIESPEOPLEHAVEEXPLAINEDTHERAINBOWINVARIOUSWAYSSOMEHAVEACCEPTEDITASAMIRACLEWITHOUTPHYSICALEXPLANATIONTOTHEHEBREWSITWASATOKENTHATTHEREWOULDBENOMOREUNIVERSALFLOODSTHEGREEKSUSEDTOIMAGINETHATITWASASIGNFROMTHEGODSTOFORETELLWARORHEAVYRAINTHENORSEMENCONSIDEREDTHERAINBOWASABRIDGEOVERWHICHTHEGODSPASSEDFROMEARTHTOTHEIRHOMEINTHESKYOTHERSHAVETRIEDTOEXPLAINTHEPHENOMENONPHYSICALLYARISTOTLETHOUGHTTHATTHERAINBOWWASCAUSEDBYREFLECTIONOFTHESUNSRAYSBYTHERAINSINCETHENPHYSICISTSHAVEFOUNDTHATITISNOTREFLECTIONBUTREFRACTIONBYTHERAINDROPSWHICHCAUSESTHERAINBOWSMANYCOMPLICATEDIDEASABOUTTHERAINBOWHAVEBEENFORMEDTHEDIFFERENCEINTHERAINBOWDEPENDSCONSIDERABLYUPONTHESIZEOFTHEDROPSANDTHEWIDTHOFTHECOLOREDBANDINCREASESASTHESIZEOFTHEDROPSINCREASESTHEACTUALPRIMARYRAINBOWOBSERVEDISSAIDTOBETHEEFFECTOFSUPERIMPOSITIONOFANUMBEROFBOWSIFTHEREDOFTHESECONDBOWFALLSUPONTHEGREENOFTHEFIRSTTHERESULTISTOGIVEABOWWITHANABNORMALLYWIDEYELLOWBANDSINCEREDANDGREENLIGHTWHENMIXEDFORMYELLOWTHISISAVERYCOMMONTYPEOFBOWONESHOWINGMAINLYREDANDYELLOWWITHLITTLEORNOGREENORBLUE

Comment: Off topic: have you heard of CryptoPals? If not, I encourage you to Google it

Comment: @enedil No I haven't, I'll check it out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing which strikes me is that the Caesar code is far too long. It's just a special case of Vigenère with a key that's one character long: I would expect that in `caesar.py` you can `from vigenere import *` and then just write a `main` method.

---

The second thing which strikes me is that it's good work for a newbie. There's a good docstring at the top; there's a `__name__ == "__main__"` check.

---

> ```
> def buildSubStrings(string, seperation): # Build all substrings required to analyse the polyalphabetic cipher
>     return [string[i::seperation] for i in range(seperation)]
> ```

Minor point: it's *separation* with two 'a's.

---

> ```
> def frequencyAnalysis(string): # Normalised frequency analysis
>     freq = [0] * 26
> ```

Magic number. For the time being I'd pull it out as a top-level constant. When you get round to handling other languages you'll need to consider passing it around, possibly implicitly (as the length of an `alphabet` object).

> ```
>     for c in string:
>         freq[ord(c) - ord('A')] += 1
> ```

There's a special class for that: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

> ```
>     total = sum(freq)
>
>     for i in range(0, len(freq)):
>         freq[i] /= (float(total) / 100)
>
>     return freq
> ```

You shouldn't need the explicit coercion to `float`: float division will do that for you. Python 3 has a different operator (`//`) for integer division. Also, it's probably more Pythonic to use a comprehension:

```
    scale = sum(freq) / 100
    return [f / scale for f in freq]
```

---

> ```
> def initialiseParser():
>     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Encrypt or decrpyt a string using the Caesar Cipher")
> ```

Typo in *decrypt*. Also, this is quoted from the Vigenère code, so looks like a copy-pasta error.

---

> ```
> def scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift): # Calculates a weighted score for a given shift value
>     englishFrequencies = [  8.167, 1.492, 2.782,
>                             4.253, 12.702, 2.228,
>                             2.015, 6.094, 6.966,
>                             0.153, 0.772, 4.025,
>                             2.406, 6.749, 7.507,
>                             1.929, 0.095, 5.987,
>                             6.327, 9.056, 2.758,
>                             0.978, 2.360, 0.150,
>                             1.974, 0.074 ]
> ```

I'd like to see a comment giving the source for these frequencies.

> ```
>     score = 0
>
>     for index in range(0, 26):
>         shiftIndex = (index + shift) % 26
>         score += abs(frequencyAnalysis[index] - englishFrequencies[shiftIndex])
>
>     return score / 26
> ```

See previous notes on the magic number and on using comprehensions.

Is the normalisation necessary? Surely you'll just be comparing scores against each other?

---

> ```
> def shiftCalculator(frequencyAnalysis): # Calculates the most likely shift value for a substring by comparing weighted scores of different shift values
>     bestGuess = ''
>     bestGuessScore = float('inf')
>
>     for shift in range(1, 27):
>         score = scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift)
>
>         if score < bestGuessScore:
>             bestGuessScore = score
>             bestGuess = chr(ord('Z') - shift + 1)
>
>     return bestGuess
> ```

There's a builtin `max` and tuples have implicit comparison, so this can be something like

```
    bestShift = max((scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis, shift), shift) for shift in range(1, 27))
    return chr(ord('Z') - bestShift[1] + 1)
```

---

> ```
>     elif args.guess:
>         maxGuess = 30 if len(strippedText) > 30 else len(strippedText)
> ```

What's the point of guessing `len(strippedText)`? I haven't seen anything which takes into account bigram frequencies, so I would think that the most plausible guess would be the key which decrypts the plaintext to `EEE...EEE`.

---

I've refactored the next section a bit to understand what it's doing:

```
        keyList = [
            ''.join(shiftCalculator(frequencyAnalysis(subString))
                for subString in buildSubStrings(strippedText, guess))
            for guess in range(2, maxGuess)
        ]
```

Given the granularity of a lot of the functions, I'm slightly surprised you didn't factor out a `guessKey(text, guess)`.

> ```
>         bestGuess = ''
>         bestGuessScore = float('inf')
>
>         for key in keyList:
>             score = scoreCalculator(frequencyAnalysis(str.upper(vigenere(strippedText, key, False))), 0)
> ```

Is the `str.upper` necessary? If so, why not apply it to `strippedText` earlier and consider in which other functions it becomes unnecessary?

---

> ```
>     if args.preserveSpacing:
>         for x in range(0, len(rawText)):
>             if rawText[x] == ' ':
> ```

The regex used `\s`, which catches a lot more than just `' '`, so that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful! There was one part that I wasn't sure about, namely your comment on how I calculate maxGuess. I did it that way to ensure that the program didn't try and guess keys that were longer than the input text, and to limit how long a key could be for performance reasons. Is there a better way of achieving this? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you've understood the opposite of what I intended to say. Certainly there's no point considering key lengths longer than the ciphertext, but my point was that there's not much point considering key lengths longer than, perhaps, a third of the length of the ciphertext.